# "Treat as atomic " effect on generated code

Tags: matlab, simulink

What impact will it cause on the generated code, if a subsystem block is marked "Treat as atomic". Even with option as unchecked, there is no use of virtual keyword in the generated code. Please explain.

Comment: The intricacies and subtleties of code generation are very difficult to explain in a Stack Overflow answer.  You're better off working through examples in the documentation, starting perhaps with [Partition Functions in the Generated Code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/examples/function-partitioning-within-the-generated-code.html)

Comment: Virtual Block means just graphical block to manage hierarchy model as I understand. Do not expect virtual keyword for generated c code function for virtual blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As a very general statement, consider:

1. During simulation, **non-atomic (virtual)** subsystems are just visual grouping elements.
2. During simulation, Simulink runs the content of **atomic subsystems** as if they were in a separate function of their own. 
   They will also appear as separate functions in the generated code (although this also depends on their function packaging attributes).

Comment: But I think "Simulink runs the content" is also right for the non-atomic subsystems. Can I ignore this property. If not, what can be the impacts. When this option should be used.